# Implement button as widget

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to implement button as a widget. The button has a primary function in app. On clicking the button in app it redirect to another fragment and play a sound. 
Is there any way to do so from widget i.e, making the  button work same function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand, you mean the launcher widget that sits on the app tray/menu? If so, just create an activity with that functionality and set it as the launcher activity. Thats the activity that will launch when the widget is tapped.